# Parent initializer not called in multi-level inheritence?

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization

I have a class scheme with 2-levels of inheritance. My expectation is that each class constructor would run through- and yet the mid-level class constructor never seems to get hit. What's missing here?

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "BASE"

class Next(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        print "NEXT"

class Final(Next):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Next, self).__init__()    
        print "FINAL"

f = Final()
```

**Outputs:**

> BASE
>   FINAL

Why does "NEXT" not print??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be calling `super()` with the *current* class, not the parent.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Base, self).__init__()
        print "BASE"

class Next(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Next, self).__init__()
        print "NEXT"

class Final(Next):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Final, self).__init__()    
        print "FINAL"

f = Final()
```

At first glance this might seem redundant ("why can't it just get the class from `self`?") - but keep in mind that the same `self` is passed to all three of these `__init__` methods when `f` is created, and that `self` is always of class `Final`. Thus, you have to pass `super()` the class that you want it to find the parent of.

Comment: the Base class should call `super()` too.

Comment: Amber- Thank you, makes perf sense

Comment: @Yarin - it's a good practice to just always call your parent's `__init__()` if you're overriding your own `__init__()`. In the case of `object` being the parent it's not necessarily a problem to not call it, unless someone is doing crazy metaprogramming stuff that modifies `object`.

Comment: It is also worth noting that Python 3.x allows you to do this the easy way and just do `super().__init__()`.

Comment: It may be interesting to note that this is one of the things they've fixed in python 3. super() "just works" : http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#super

Comment: it's not only when people modify object. there are many more situations when not calling super() on the base will violate mro lookup, see http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/

Answer (score 1):

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "BASE"

class Next(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Next, self).__init__()
        print "NEXT"

class Final(Next):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Final, self).__init__()    
        print "FINAL"

f = Final()
```

Comment: In class_name and super(class_name, self).__init__...  both must have same claaname to print all call methods but in Class Next(Bass) there is super(Bass, self)__init__ ..so "NEXT" not printed.....so change super(Next, self).__init__... then o/p:  BASE  NEXT  FINAL